# Rails sanitize user input in active record query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Let's say I have following data:

`models/supplier.rb`

```
| -- | ---------------- |
| id | name             |
| -- | ---------------- |
| 1  | John Doe's Store |
| 2  | Jane             |
| -- | ---------------- |
```

I have following queries which are failing to sanitize user's input from search field:

```
@term = "John Doe's"
```

**Query 1**

```
Supplier.order("case when name LIKE :term 1 else 2 end, name asc", term: "#{@term}%")

ArgumentError: Direction "one's%" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1113:in `block (2 levels) in validate_order_args'
```

**Query 2**

> Vulnerable to SQL Injection attack

```
Supplier.order("case when name LIKE '#{@term}%' then 1 else 2 end, name ASC").first
  
Supplier Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "suppliers".* FROM "suppliers"  ORDER BY case when name LIKE 'John Doe's%' then 1 else 2 end LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "s"
LINE 1: ...uppliers"  ORDER BY case when name LIKE 'John Doe's%' then 1..
```

**Query 3**

> It will success for normal inputs which don't have `'` (special character) in them, but this query is still vulnerable to SQL injection attack

```
@term = "John"

Supplier.order("case when name LIKE '#{@term}%' then 1 else 2 end, name ASC").first

#<Supplier:0x007fe4bfd8d758
 id: 188,
 name: "John Doe's Store">
```

I am not able to figure out a solution for this problem, Please help me complete this query in secure way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to escape your input is to use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(value)
```

This works for all types and is what rails use.

```
@term =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote("John Doe's" + "%" )

Supplier.order("case when name LIKE #{@term} then 1 else 2 end, name ASC").first
```

Comment: Hey `GorillaApe`, yes I tried with `sanitize`, and `quote` too, but looks like the problem is `order` is not respecting `sanitized` input, and raising errors in those cases.

Comment: damn! the problem wasn't the `sanitize` or `quote` not working, the problem was the extra `%` in the sql query :D :D, Thank you very much `GorillaApe`.

Comment: Note that sanitize is depreciated for rails 5 as far as I know. Glad to help

Comment: App, you are right, I noticed that and using `connection.quote`, Thanks for the info

Comment: BEWARE: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28947#issuecomment-440982901 quote will use a DB connection, so if you are doing a lot of quoting, this might be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Rails offers `sanitize_sql_like()` for this.

So your example would look like this:

```
@term = "John Doe's"

like_value = sanitize_sql_like(@term + '%')

Supplier.order("case when name LIKE #{like_value} 1 else 2 end, name asc")
```

> See:
> https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_like

EDIT:

If you need to use it in a Controller, call it like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize_sql_like()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the base connection quote which will sanitize the input

```
@term = "John Doe's"

like_value = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(@term + '%') 

Supplier.order("case when name LIKE #{like_value} 1 else 2 end, name asc")
```

Read about it here...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote

Comment: BEWARE: github.com/rails/rails/issues/28947#issuecomment-440982901 quote will use a DB connection, so if you are doing a lot of quoting, this might be an issue.